# multiple jar folders

Tags: android, ant

I have a main android app which has 2 jars in it's libs folder. This android app includes a Java Source Project which has about 4 jars in it's libs folder.

In the build.xml I have copied from android's build.xml the 'target name="-compile">'.

and added this:

```
    <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping..." >

        <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->

        <path id="project.javac.classpath" >

            <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />

            <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
        </path>
 <javac
  bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
  classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
  debug="true"
  destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
  encoding="${java.encoding}"
  extdirs=""
  fork="${need.javac.fork}"
  includeantruntime="false"
  source="${java.source}"
  target="${java.target}"
  verbose="${verbose}" >
  <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
  <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
  <src path="${javaproject.dir}" /> #THIS IS WHAT I ADDED which is defined in ANT.PROPERTIES
  <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
</javac>
```

So it references the java source project. The problem happens with the java source project's jars which are in folder libs. 
How do I also include them?

ps. copying them to android project's libs folder is not an option.

Comment: The build-time classpath in this case is controlled by the definition of path statement with the id `project.javac.classpath`.  If you can post that snippet, it should be possible to tell you how to change it around to pick up the jars.

Comment: @David hopefully I added the correct snippet. Check my original post above the <javac> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:

```
<javac
     bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
     classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
     debug="true"
     destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
     encoding="${java.encoding}"
     extdirs=""
     fork="${need.javac.fork}"
     includeantruntime="false"
     target="${java.target}"
     verbose="${verbose}"

     source="${java.source}">

     <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
     <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
     <src path="${javaproject.dir}" /> #THIS IS WHAT I ADDED which is defined in ANT.PROPERTIES

    <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
</javac>
```

Notice you've specified both the `source` parameter and the `<src path>` sub-entity. Also notice that you have a reference to `javaproject.dir`. What is this directory? Is it the source of the other project, the other project's main directory, or something else?

First, you shouldn't use both `<src path>` and the `srcdir` parameters in your `<javac>` command. If you need only a single source directory path, you can use either the `srcdir` parameter of the `<javac>` task, or the `<src path>` sub-entity. If you have more than one, you should not use `srcdir`, and only use the `<src path>` sub-entity.

Now back to your question...

If I understand you correctly, you want to specify multiple classpath folders in your `<javac>` task. You can do this by removing the `classpath` or `classpathref` parameters of the `<javac>` command, and simply specify multiple `<classpath path>` sub-entities like you do with source directories.

I think you want something like this:

```
<javac
     bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
     debug="true"
     destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
     encoding="${java.encoding}"
     extdirs=""
     fork="${need.javac.fork}"
     includeantruntime="false"
     target="${java.target}"
     verbose="${verbose}">

     <!-- Here I can specify multiple classpaths: -->
     <!-- Either classpath references, or classpath elements -->
     <classpath refid="project.javac.classpath"/>
     <classpath refid="some.other.classpath.reference"/>
     <classpath path="${some.actual.directory.with.jars}"/>

     <src path="${java.source}">
     <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
     <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
     <!-- <src path="${javaproject.dir}" />  Is this correct? -->

     <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
</javac>
```

Comment: you've been a big help. thank you.

to answer the questions:
javaproject.dir = the other project's src dir.

about the 'source' parameter, all it does is tell javac that the java version is 1.5.
and the 'srcdir' parameter I never use it.

Comment: above comment is not correct.

still doesnt work. When I compile I get the following errors since the libs are not there:
  [javac] /somepath/src/si/sis/toliti/game/button/BoardButton.java:13: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Sprite
    [javac] location: class si.sis.toliti.game.button.BoardButton
    [javac]  private Sprite buttonSprite;


to answer the questions:
javaproject.dir = the other project's src dir.

about the 'source' parameter, all it does is tell javac that the java version is 1.5.
and the 'srcdir' parameter I never use it.

Comment: Sorry. Confused `srcdir` with `source`.

Comment: What do you mean _libs are not there_? Do you mean that there is no jar file that contains the class? Is that a class that is compiled, and another source file depends upon?

Comment: the android projects dependss on the JAVA SOURCE PROJECT which this takes care of which leads to the 'src' dir:
`<src path="${javaproject.dir}"/>`
but on this JAVA PROJECT there are also 'jar' file in the libs folder. And here lies the problem/

Comment: Why can't you specify that _lib folder_ that contains the jar as part of the `<classpath>` sub-entity?

Comment: In my example, I not only showed you how to have multiple `<classpath>` elements in your `<javac>` task, but I also showed two different ways. See the Ant manual about specifying [`<classpath>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) for even more ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `<path>` to contain all the jars your project depends on at build-time and reference it in your `<javac>` task.  You've already got the latter working with the classpathref to "project.javac.classpath", so you need to make that path include the jars.

For example:

```
<path id="project.javac.classpath">
    <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
    <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
    <!-- include all the jar files under /path/to/your/jars" -->
    <fileset dir="/path/to/your/jars">
        <!-- the **/* pattern recurses subdirectories -->
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

That path includes a reference to "project.all.jars.path", which is probably where you really want to make the changes I noted to pick up the additional jars.

Comment: doesn't work. Upon launch I get error:
E/AndroidRuntime(17393): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.name.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

It works for me to build an additional path following in David's solution. 
I added a if condition to check the additional lib path was needed or not.

```
<condition property="android.additional.libdir.enabled" value="true" else="false">
    <and>
       <isset property="android.additional.lib.dir" />
    </and>
</condition>

<if condition="${android.additional.libdir.enabled}">
   <then>
      <path id="project.javac.classpath">
           <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
           <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
           <fileset dir="${android.additional.lib.dir}">
               <include name="**/*.jar"/>
           </fileset>
      </path>
   </then>
   <else>
      <path id="project.javac.classpath">
          <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
          <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
      </path> 
   </else>
</if>
```

In the ant.properties file, specify the additional lib directory path.

`android.additional.lib.dir=yourpath`